# Is this set-theoretic motivation for conditional probability correct?

Tags: measure-theory

Given a set $\Omega$ with a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$ defined on it. Let B be a subset of $\Omega$ and define

$ B \cap \mathcal{F} = \{B \cap F : F \in \mathcal{F} \} $. Call this $\mathcal{F}_B$.

The claim is that this collection of sets is a $\sigma$-field and hence (B, $\mathcal{F}_B$) is a measurable space.

I don't see why $\mathcal{F}_B$ is a $\sigma$-field just because it is a subset of one. Any insight appreciated.

Comment: List the required properties of a sigma field, and show how $\mathcal F_B$ qualifies for them.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\sigma$-field? Have you tried to apply it to $B\cap F$?

Comment: This is called trace sigma algebra. Look it up.

Comment: @Kemp and Myerson yes and yes. However, I was basing it on the wrong generating set - the B in the measurable space should have jumped out at me but it didn't.

Comment: @Snoop, thanks for the lead.

Comment: OK, so, does that mean that now you know how to solve the problem, Tony? If so, let me encourage you to write it up and to post it as an answer.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that, Tony.

Comment: @myerson: I've been at my island retreat and off the net. I'll take a crack at it tomorrow.

Comment: To all, if the above edit to my question qualifies as an answer I'll post if as such and close this question. If not, I ask some kind person to post an answer.

Comment: If by "displaymode" you mean $$\rm this,$$ it's done with double dollar signs on both sides.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. I'll remember that. And my proof, is it good to go or did I really screw the pooch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested proof. (Axioms are $\sigma$-algebra axioms.) Notation different from question.

Let ($\star$) be

$B \cap \mathcal{E} := \{B \cap E, E \in \mathcal{E}\} = \mathcal{E}_B$

To prove the claim it is a $\sigma$-algebra on $B$ we need to show:

(i) $B \in \mathcal{E}_B$

(ii) $(B \cap E)^c$ in $\mathcal{E}_B$  $\; \forall E \in \mathcal{E}$.

(iii) $\mathcal{E}_B$ satisfies $\sigma$-additivity.

Proof of (i): We know that $\Omega$ is in $\mathcal{E}$ by Axiom (1).

Therefore, by ($\star$), $(B \cap \Omega) \in \mathcal{E}_B$.

But
$B \cap \Omega = B$, hence $B \in \mathcal{E}_B$.

Proof of (ii): $(B \cap E)^c = (B^c \cup E^c)$ (de Morgan).

Now $B^c$ and $E^c$ are in $\mathcal{E}$ by Axiom (2) and their union
is in $\mathcal{E}$ by Axiom (3).

Hence, by ($\star$) $B \cap (B^c \cup E^c) \in \mathcal{E}_B$.

But $(B^c \cup E^c) =
(\Omega \cup \Omega) = \Omega$, and $B \cap \Omega = B$ which is in $\mathcal{E}_B$ by (i).

Proof of (iii):  Let $E_j \in \mathcal{E}$.

We want to show that
$$
\bigcup_{j\in \mathcal{N}} (B \cup E_j) \in \mathcal{E}_B. 
$$

But,
$$
\bigcup_{j\in \mathcal{N}} (B \cup E_j) = B \cap
\bigcup_{j\in \mathcal{N}} E_J 
$$
by Distributive Law. Let
$$
\bigcup_{j\in \mathcal{N}} E_J = X, \; \text{ say, then } X \in \mathcal{E}
$$
by Axiom (3).

Hence, by $(\star)$  $(B \cap X) \in \mathcal{E}_B$